# Ruby on Rails Error: Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble initializing a new Rails application under `Desktop/rails_projects`. According to another post, I have to empty the affected directory, which prevents me from creating a new project. The post said I'll find `.bundle folder` if I look inside with `ls -a`.

However, the my problems is that I have created rails_projects just before creating a new Rails application, which means there's nothing there. Also, I've tried created another folder under `Desktop/aNewFolder` and same thing happens. Maybe there's a problem with Desktop itself? I'm not sure. I did `ls -a` on `Desktop` but I couldn't find `.bundle folder.` Also, I can't just erase everything in my desktop. That's absurd.

This is what I've got when I tried to do `$rails new first_app` inside `Desktop/rails_projects`:

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help.
```

And received this when I typed rails:

```
The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 benchmarker  See how fast a piece of code runs
 profiler     Get profile information from a piece of code
 plugin       Install a plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Type `rails console`... does it try to open up a console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a directory under rails_projects first, `mkdir first_app`, then run your `rails new first_app` command.

If `first_app` already exists, remove it first or pick another directory/application name.

Comment: Again, thanks for your advice. I tried creating a new directory under Desktop/rails_projects/projects/. However, it still resulted the same issue. So I've tried creating a new folder or rails app in other root folder, such as Document or under ~/, and it worked. Even though I can now develop a ruby app, I can't create anything under Desktop. I'm hoping there's a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

In my case I realized that all files in a project structure were created under the user `C:\Users\Sergio`. App folders, bin, config, db, lib, log, public, test, tmp and vendor. 
The solution in this case was to delete the files and aptana started functioning normally.

Answer (score -1):

**[image] (same problem)** actually i had same problem like this.

now i got the solution about this.
i hope you will solve this problem with my solution.

> **[image]**
>
> **(look at this while reading below solutions)**
>
> 1. look at your command(bash) If the current position "yourId:~/workspace", Go to the preceding folder -> **"cd .."**
> 2. **"ls"** -> input in your command again. then you can see like this Three-file. (check-invironment*, lib/, workspace/)
> 3. *The reason your project was not operated is about the directory "workspace".* so you MUST REMOVE YOUR "WORKSPACE" directory. -> **"rm -rf
>      workspace/"**
> 4. check whether the folder is deleted. -> **"ls"** again.
> 5. if you removed the "workspace", you'll see the TWO THIGS (check-invironment*, lib/)
> 6. after removing, make a new workspace again. -> **"mkdir workspace"**
> 7. now you can make the new app. -> **"rails new appname_you_want" or "rails *5.0.0.1* new appname_you_want"**

Comment: I am just curious to know why the post has -1. is it owing to deleting of workspace folder?